# Swift 5 : Resizing a button according to titleLabel length with padding

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uistackview

I have a horizontal `UIStackView` which contains an `UILabel` and a `UIButton`.

My `UILabel` is correctly fitting and wrapping a the middle of the `UIStackView` but the issue is that my `UIButton` has either a truncated content in the middle or no padding.

What I do is :

```
        let container = UIStackView()
        self.addSubview(container)
        container.addArrangedSubview(debateName)
        container.addArrangedSubview(debateButton)
        container.axis = .horizontal
        container.distribution = .equalSpacing
        container.alignment = .center
        container.spacing = 15
        container.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
        container.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 15)
        container.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
        container.addBorder(hexString: SettingsProvider.sharedInstance.borderBoxColor, width: 0.2)
        container.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.top.equalTo(self)
            make.left.equalTo(self)
            make.right.equalTo(self)
            make.height.greaterThanOrEqualTo(100)
        }
        
        myLabel.numberOfLines = 0

        myButton.setTitle(NSLocalizedString(self.textKey, comment: ""), for: .normal)
        myButton.uppercased()
        myButton.layer.cornerRadius = 6
        myButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 10, bottom: 8, right: 10)
        myButton.sizeToFit()
        myButton.addBorder(hexString: SettingsProvider.sharedInstance.borderBoxColor, width: 0.2)
        myButton.addShadow(offset: CGSize.init(width: 0, height: 1), color: UIColor.init(hexString: SettingsProvider.sharedInstance.borderBoxColor), radius: 4, opacity: 0.35)
```

The only thing I can do is removing `contentEdgeInsets()` so I can have my content not truncated but I lose my padding :

[image]

[image]

Is there any way to combine those two requirements ?

Comment: I figured out that I can reduce the spacing between elements in my UIStackView but it is more of a "trick" than a real solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things...

- on your stack view, set `.distribution = .fill` instead of `.equalSpacing`. You have only two arranged subviews (there's only one space)
- you shouldn't need `myButton.sizeToFit()`

Add this line to your button setup:

```
myButton.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
```

That should prevent your button from compressing / truncating its label.

Comment: Worked well. Thanks